# JS functional programming for n items populate

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I'm trying to write code in a more functional style, and a problem I keep encountering is populating an array of `n` items.

For example:

```
const items[];

for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    items.push(new Item());
}
```

If I understand correctly, there are two side effects here: `i` is mutating and `items` is as well.

I'm wondering what is the "pure" way to do this in Javascript.  I've tried stuff like `(new Array(n)).map(...)` and `(new Array(n)).forEach(...)` but I'm not sure why these would be better or worse.  Can someone elaborate, or point me to a post that covers this topic?

Comment: A mutating local variable that is not seen externally is perfectly acceptable in functional style.

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.fill()` instead.

Comment: @Redu: If you use that with an object reference (e.g., `new Item()`), you will end up with `n` copies of the same instance, instead of `n` separate instances...

Comment: @mellamokb you are right of course but that's not what i mean. What i wanted to say was, as mentioned in the question Array map or Array forEach wouldn't iterate over new Array(n) since it's items are undefined. Has to be like `(new Array(n)).fill("You got it?").map(e => new Item())`

Comment: @mellamokb: That shouldn't matter, given the OP is interested in functional programming :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution seems like a good option:

```
const n = 10;
const items = Array.from(Array(n), x => new Item());
```

Check more about the [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

---

[This article](http://stephen-young.me.uk/2013/01/20/functional-programming-with-javascript.html) gives a good level of details for functional programming in Javascript.